# Would a StopIteration make python slow?

Tags: python, for-loop, stopiteration

As far as i know, monitoring exception will make a program slower.

Would an iterator exception monitor, such as `StopIteration` make a `for` loop slower?

Comment: I fail to see the point: where is this `StopIteration` supposed to come from? Normally, it is monitored by the iteraator itself.

Comment: @glglgl Yes,it's monitored by the iterator..So I'm don't understand why not iterator use a hasnext function instead of raise StopIteration Exception?use iterator is so common,I think it will improve performance a lot

Comment: Unlike other languages like C++ where using exceptions is an order of magnitude slower than regular code, exception handling in Python is about the same speed as any other code. I would not worry about it unless you've done profiling that tells you that there is an issue for your specific use.

Comment: @Blckknght cool,would you mind share the reason why python's exception   handling so fast.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While exception monitoring has some small overhead in the usual case, in the case of iterators there does not appear to be any overhead involved in handling `StopIteration` exceptions. Python optimises iterators as a special case so that `StopIteration` doesn't involve any exception handlers. (I'll also observe---and I may be missing something---that it's hard to come up with a Python `for` loop that doesn't implicitly use iterators).

Here's some examples, first using the built-in `range` function and a simple `for` loop:

```
Python 2.7.5
>>> import dis
>>> def x():
...   for i in range(1,11):
...     pass
...
>>> dis.dis(x)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              23 (to 26)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (11)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             15 GET_ITER
        >>   16 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 25)
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
        >>   25 POP_BLOCK
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note that range is essentially being treated as an iterator.

Now, using a simple generator function:

```
>>> def g(x):
...   while x < 11:
...     yield x
...     x = x + 1
...
>>> def y():
...   for i in g(1):
...     pass
...
>>> dis.dis(y)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 23)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (g)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 22)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   22 POP_BLOCK
        >>   23 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(g)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              31 (to 34)
        >>    3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (11)
              9 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             12 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       33

  3          15 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             18 YIELD_VALUE
             19 POP_TOP

  4          20 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             23 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             26 BINARY_ADD
             27 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             30 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   33 POP_BLOCK
        >>   34 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             37 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note that `y` here is basically the same as `x` above, the difference being one `LOAD_CONST` instruction, since `x` references the number 11. Likewise, our simple generator is basically equivalent to the same thing written as a while loop:

```
>>> def q():
...   x = 1
...   while x < 11:
...     x = x + 1
...
>>> dis.dis(q)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           6 SETUP_LOOP              26 (to 35)
        >>    9 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (11)
             15 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       34

  4          21 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             24 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             27 BINARY_ADD
             28 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             31 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            9
        >>   34 POP_BLOCK
        >>   35 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE
```

Again, there's no specific overhead to handle the iterator or the generator (`range` may be somewhat more optimised than the generator version, simply because its a built-in, but not due to the way Python handles it).

Finally, let's look at an actual explicit iterator written with `StopIteration`

```
>>> class G(object):
...   def __init__(self, x):
...     self.x = x
...   def __iter__(self):
...     return self
...   def next(self):
...     x = self.x
...     if x >= 11:
...       raise StopIteration
...     x = x + 1
...     return x - 1
...
>>> dis.dis(G.next)
  7           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (x)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (x)

  8           9 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (11)
             15 COMPARE_OP               5 (>=)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       30

  9          21 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (StopIteration)
             24 RAISE_VARARGS            1
             27 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 30)

 10     >>   30 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             33 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             36 BINARY_ADD
             37 STORE_FAST               1 (x)

 11          40 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             43 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             46 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             47 RETURN_VALUE
```

Now, here we can see that the generator function involves a few less instructions than this simple iterator, mostly related to the differences in implementation and a couple of instructions related to raising the `StopIteration` exception. Nevertheless, a function using this iterator is exactly equivalent to `y` above:

```
>>> def z():
...   for i in G(1):
...     pass
...
>>> dis.dis(z)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 23)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (G)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 22)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   22 POP_BLOCK
        >>   23 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

Of course, these results are based around the fact that Python for-loops will optimise iterators to remove the need for explicit handlers for the `StopIteration` exception. After all, `StopIteration` exception essentially form a normal part of the operation of a Python for-loop.

---

Regarding *why* it is implemented this way, see [PEP-234](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/) which defines iterators. This specifically addresses the issue of the expense of the exception:

> - It has been questioned whether an exception to signal the end of
>       the iteration isn't too expensive.  Several alternatives for the
>       StopIteration exception have been proposed: a special value End
>       to signal the end, a function end() to test whether the iterator
>       is finished, even reusing the IndexError exception.
>
>   - A special value has the problem that if a sequence ever
>       contains that special value, a loop over that sequence will
>       end prematurely without any warning.  If the experience with
>       null-terminated C strings hasn't taught us the problems this
>       can cause, imagine the trouble a Python introspection tool
>       would have iterating over a list of all built-in names,
>       assuming that the special End value was a built-in name!
>   - Calling an end() function would require two calls per
>       iteration.  Two calls is much more expensive than one call
>       plus a test for an exception.  Especially the time-critical
>       for loop can test very cheaply for an exception.
>   - Reusing IndexError can cause confusion because it can be a
>       genuine error, which would be masked by ending the loop
>       prematurely.

Comment: 3x~That's what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the output of the bytecode generated by a function with a `try` and `except` block, it looks like it would be slightly slower, however, this is honestly negligible in most circumstances, as it is *extremely* small as far as performance hit goes. I think the real thing to consider when doing an optimization like this would be *scoping* the exceptions properly.

Output of an example function with `try`/`except` block when compiled to bytecode:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> def x():
    try:
        sd="lol"
    except:
        raise


>>> dis.dis(x)
  2           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            10 (to 13)

  3           3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('lol')
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (sd)
              9 POP_BLOCK           
             10 JUMP_FORWARD            10 (to 23)

  4     >>   13 POP_TOP             
             14 POP_TOP             
             15 POP_TOP             

  5          16 RAISE_VARARGS            0
             19 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 23)
             22 END_FINALLY         
        >>   23 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

Comment: Yes,use try..except make a program slower.Why python use raise StopIteration for iterator end signal.Why don't just use a function hasnext which return boolean value?